# tkinter is creating extra buttons when selecting different radio options

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to make a multipanel GUI for entering variables for running a regression tree script. I want to be able to have the GUI take the selections for specific options and send the users to the specific panel to fill out. I found a way to create the button to go to a different panel based on which option is selected but it is creating a new button every time I change the radiobutton selection in the StartPage class.
[image]

Is there an easier way to filter which panels will be displayed, or just update the text/command of the button?

```
import tkinter as tk

class ModelingGUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        
        subFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        subFrame.pack(anchor='n')
        Hyper = tk.Label(subFrame, text = "Run Parameter Optimization?")
        Hyper.pack(side = 'left')
        HParam = tk.StringVar()
        HParam.set('PageOne')

        def ParamChoice():
            ParamChoice = tk.StringVar()    
            ParamChoice = HParam.get()
            if ParamChoice =='PageOne':
               
                NextButton1 = tk.Button(self, text = ParamChoice, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
                NextButton1.pack()
                                    
            if ParamChoice =='PageTwo':
                NextButton2 = tk.Button(self, text = ParamChoice, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
                NextButton2.pack()
                      
        R2 = tk.Radiobutton(subFrame, text = 'No', variable=HParam, value='PageOne', command=ParamChoice)
        R1 = tk.Radiobutton(subFrame, text = 'Yes', variable=HParam, value='PageTwo', command=ParamChoice)
        
        R2.pack(side = 'right')
        R1.pack(side = 'right')

class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        WelcomeLabel = tk.Label(self,text = "Explicit Hyperparameter Settings")
        WelcomeLabel.pack(side = 'top')

        BackButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Back',command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        BackButton.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        
        WelcomeLabel = tk.Label(self,text = "Find Optimized Hyperparameters")
        WelcomeLabel.pack(side = 'top')

        BackButton = tk.Button(self, text = 'Back',command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        BackButton.pack()

app = ModelingGUI()
app.mainloop()
```

I've tried putting .destoy() in the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the button once and update its text and command options inside `ParamChoice()` function:

```py
class StartPage(tk.Frame):   
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        subFrame = tk.Frame(self)
        subFrame.pack(anchor='n')

        Hyper = tk.Label(subFrame, text="Run Parameter Optimization?")
        Hyper.pack(side='left')

        HParam = tk.StringVar()
        HParam.set('PageOne')

        def ParamChoice():
            choice = HParam.get()
            if choice == 'PageOne':
                NextButton.config(text=choice, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
            elif choice == 'PageTwo':
                NextButton.config(text=choice, command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
                      
        R2 = tk.Radiobutton(subFrame, text='No', variable=HParam, value='PageOne', command=ParamChoice)
        R1 = tk.Radiobutton(subFrame, text='Yes', variable=HParam, value='PageTwo', command=ParamChoice)
        NextButton = tk.Button(self) # create the button

        R2.pack(side='right')
        R1.pack(side='right')
        NextButton.pack()

        ParamChoice() # initialize the NextButton
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, that fixed it. Now I can stop trying to put my head through the wall on this problem.